# What's the most Pythonic/efficient way to conditionally split lengthy rows?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I have a data frame with a column `Results` which can get pretty lengthy. Since the data frame is ending up in an Excel report, this is problematic as Excel will only make a row so tall before it just simply doesn't display all data. Instead, what I'd like to do is split rows with results of a certain length into multiple rows.

I wrote some code on a small scale data frame to split the results into chunks of 2. I haven't worked out how to put each chunk in a new row. Additionally, I'm not sure this will be the most efficient method when my data frame goes from 6 rows to 35k+. What is the most efficient/Pythonic way to achieve what I want?

Original data frame

```
                        Result        Date
0                    [SUCCESS]  10/10/2019
1                    [SUCCESS]  10/09/2019
2                    [FAILURE]  10/08/2019
3  [Pending, Pending, SUCCESS]  10/07/2019
4                    [FAILURE]  10/06/2019
5           [Pending, SUCCESS]  10/05/2019
```

Goal output

```
               Result        Date
0           [SUCCESS]  10/10/2019
1           [SUCCESS]  10/09/2019
2           [FAILURE]  10/08/2019
3  [Pending, Pending]  10/07/2019
4           [SUCCESS]  10/07/2019
5           [FAILURE]  10/06/2019
6  [Pending, SUCCESS]  10/05/2019
```

Code

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = {'Result': [['SUCCESS'], ['SUCCESS'], ['FAILURE'], ['Pending', 'Pending', 'SUCCESS'], ['FAILURE'], ['Pending', 'SUCCESS']], 'Date': ['10/10/2019', '10/09/2019', '10/08/2019', '10/07/2019', '10/06/2019', '10/05/2019']}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df['Length of Results'] = df['Result'].str.len()

def chunks(l, n):
    for i in range(0, len(l), n):
        yield l[i:i + n]

for i in range(len(df)):
    if df['Length of Results'][i] > 2:
        df['Result'][i] = list(chunks(df['Result'][i], 2))
    else:
        pass

df['Chunks'] = 1
for i in range(len(df)):
    if df['Length of Results'][i] > 2:
        df['Chunks'][i] = len(df['Result'][i])
    else:
        pass

df = df.loc[np.repeat(df.index.values, df.Chunks)]
df = df.reset_index(drop=True)
```

Code currently produces

```
                            Result        Date  Length of Results  Chunks
0                        [SUCCESS]  10/10/2019                  1       1
1                        [SUCCESS]  10/09/2019                  1       1
2                        [FAILURE]  10/08/2019                  1       1
3  [[Pending, Pending], [SUCCESS]]  10/07/2019                  3       2
4  [[Pending, Pending], [SUCCESS]]  10/07/2019                  3       2
5                        [FAILURE]  10/06/2019                  1       1
6               [Pending, SUCCESS]  10/05/2019                  2       1
```

df.to_dict()

```
{'Result': {0: ['SUCCESS'], 1: ['SUCCESS'], 2: ['FAILURE'], 3: [['Pending', 'Pending'], ['SUCCESS']], 4: [['Pending', 'Pending'], ['SUCCESS']], 5: ['FAILURE'], 6: ['Pending', 'SUCCESS']}, 'Date': {0: '10/10/2019', 1: '10/09/2019', 2: '10/08/2019', 3: '10/07/2019', 4: '10/07/2019', 5: '10/06/2019', 6: '10/05/2019'}, 'Length of Results': {0: 1, 1: 1, 2: 1, 3: 3, 4: 3, 5: 1, 6: 2}, 'Chunks': {0: 1, 1: 1, 2: 1, 3: 2, 4: 2, 5: 1, 6: 1}}
```

Comment: IMHO, it's a terrible idea putting lists in pandas cells.

Comment: also can you show us the df.to_dict()?

Comment: @WeNYoBen added to original question

Comment: @QuangHoang I agree, do you have any alternate suggestions of how I can handle this data for my purposes?

Comment: Is there an ID field that attributes the data to some entity? If so, you should just make your data long instead of short i.e. Row 1 : id=1, date: 20191010, value: Success Row 2:  id=1, date: 20191011, value: Failure

Comment: How lengthy is “pretty lengthy”? Is there any way this problem could be avoided by making changes earlier in the program?

Answer (score 1):

You can do

```
s=df[['Date','Result']].explode('Result')

t=s.groupby(['Date','Result'])['Result'].transform('size')>1
s.groupby([s.Date,t]).Result.agg(list).reset_index(level=0).reset_index(drop=True)
Out[65]: 
         Date              Result
0  10/05/2019  [Pending, SUCCESS]
1  10/06/2019           [FAILURE]
2  10/07/2019           [SUCCESS]
3  10/07/2019  [Pending, Pending]
4  10/08/2019           [FAILURE]
5  10/09/2019           [SUCCESS]
6  10/10/2019           [SUCCESS]
```

Comment: It looks great, but I'm not sure how to get it back into my data frame so it looks like the goal output.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend putting each `pending/SUCCESS/FAILURE` on one row, using `df.explode` if you are on pandas 0.25+:

```
df = df.explode('Result')
df.groupby(['Date','Result']).count().reset_index(name='Length')
```

Output:

```
         Date   Result  Length
0  10/05/2019  Pending       1
1  10/05/2019  SUCCESS       1
2  10/06/2019  FAILURE       1
3  10/07/2019  Pending       2
4  10/07/2019  SUCCESS       1
5  10/08/2019  FAILURE       1
6  10/09/2019  SUCCESS       1
7  10/10/2019  SUCCESS       1
```